# How can I programmatically give Cloud ML access to a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab, google-cloud-ml

The [Cloud ML instructions](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/how-tos/using-external-buckets#step_2_configure_access_to_your_cloud_storage_bucket) show how to grant Cloud ML access to a bucket using gsutil. Is there a way to do this programmatically in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [google-cloud](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/) python libraries to programmatically give access to a GCS bucket to Cloud ML.

```
from google.cloud import storage
b = client.get_bucket(BUCKET)

# Grant WRITE access to the service account.
b.acl.user(SERVICE_ACCOUNT).grant_write()
b.acl.save()

# Change the default object permissions to give read access to the service account
b.default_object_acl.user(SERVICE_ACCOUNT).grant_read()
b.default_object_acl.save()

# Grant read access to all existing objects
for o in b.list_blobs():
  o.acl.user(SERVICE_ACCOUNT).grant_read()
  o.acl.save()
```

For instructions on obtaining the service account programmatically see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198449/how-can-i-get-the-cloud-ml-service-account-programmatically-in-python)