# How to read a jpg. from google storage as a path or file type

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

As the topic indicates...

I have try two ways and none of them work:

**First:**

I　want to programmatically talk to GCS in Python.　such as reading gs://{bucketname}/{blobname} as a path or a file. The only thing I can find is a gsutil module, however it seems used in a commend line instead of a python application.

i find a code here [Accessing data in google cloud bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41460802/accessing-data-in-google-cloud-bucket-for-a-python-tensorflow-learning-program), but still confused on how to retrieve it to a type i need. there is a jpg file in the bucket, and want to download it for a text detection, this will be  deploy on google funtion.

**Second:**

`download_as_bytes()`method, [Link to the blob document](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/blob/main/google/cloud/storage/blob.py) I import the `googe.cloud.storage` module and provide the GCP key, however the error rise saying the Blob has no attribute of download_as_bytes().

is there anything else i haven't try? Thank you!

for the reference:

```
def text_detected(user_id):
    
    bucket=storage_client.bucket(
'img_platecapture')
    blob=bucket.blob({user_id})
    content= blob.download_as_bytes()

    image = vision.Image(content=content) #insert a content
    response = vision_client.text_detection(image=image)    

    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))

    img = Image.open(input_file) #insert a path
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    font = ImageFont.truetype("simsun.ttc", 18)

    for text in response.text_annotations[1::]:
        ocr = text.description
        draw.text((bound.vertices[0].x-25, bound.vertices[0].y-25),ocr,fill=(255,0,0),font=font)
        
        draw.polygon(
            [
                bound.vertices[0].x,
                bound.vertices[0].y,
                bound.vertices[1].x,
                bound.vertices[1].y,
                bound.vertices[2].x,
                bound.vertices[2].y,
                bound.vertices[3].x,
                bound.vertices[3].y,
            ],
            None,
            'yellow',
        
            )

    texts=response.text_annotations
    a=str(texts[0].description.split())

    b=re.sub(u"([^\u4e00-\u9fa5\u0030-u0039])","",a)
    b1="".join(b)
    print("偵測到的地址為:",b1)  
    return b1
   
@handler.add(MessageEvent, message=ImageMessage)
def handle_content_message(event):
    message_content = line_bot_api.get_message_content(event.message.id)
    user = line_bot_api.get_profile(event.source.user_id)

    data=b''
    for chunk in message_content.iter_content():
       data+= chunk
   
    global bucket_name   
    bucket_name = 'img_platecapture'
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(f'{user.user_id}.jpg')
    blob.upload_from_string(data)
    text_detected1=text_detected(user.user_id) ####Here's the problem
    
    line_bot_api.reply_message(
        event.reply_token,
        messages=TextSendMessage(
            text=text_detected1
    ))
```

reference code(gcsfs/fsspec):

```
gcs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem()
bucket=storage_client.bucket('img_platecapture')
blob=bucket.blob({user_id}) 

f =fsspec.open("gs://img_platecapture/{user_id}")
with f.open({user_id}, "rb") as fp:
  content = fp.read()

image = vision.Image(content=content)
response = vision_client.text_detection(image=image)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#prereq-code-samples) `Python` client :

```py
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

    # The ID of your GCS object
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    # The path to which the file should be downloaded
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Construct a client side representation of a blob.
    # Note `Bucket.blob` differs from `Bucket.get_blob` as it doesn't retrieve
    # any content from Google Cloud Storage. As we don't need additional data,
    # using `Bucket.blob` is preferred here.
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)

    # blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
    # blob.download_as_string()

    blob.download_as_bytes()

    print(
        "Downloaded storage object {} from bucket {} to local file {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, bucket_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```

You can use the following methods :

```py
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
    blob.download_as_string()

    blob.download_as_bytes()
```

To be able to correctly use this library, you have to install the expected [pip package](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/) in your virtual env.

Example of project structure :

```
my-project
    requirements.txt
    your_python_script.py
```

The requirements.txt file :

```
google-cloud-storage==2.6.0
```

Run the following command :

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

In your case maybe the package was not installed correctly in your virtual env, that's why you could not access to the `download_as_bytes` method.

Comment: thank you for the detailed information, yes i do also install google-cloud-storage. then still rise this error. however, i realize that for an object detection, i need to have both "the content" and "a path", as i just have add the code reference on my post. therefore even i can use download as string() or download as bytes(), i still need to figure out a way to get a path. do you have any ideas on this? thank you!

Comment: When you say `path`, do you mean Python import `path` ?

Comment: @ Mazlum Tosun thank you for the reply, in the project here, I also use a PIL module to draw, the `path`  i try to clearified here is more like a literrally saying file path for reaching the csv file. because i have this code ` img = Image.open(input_file) '  input_file here is the path i want to point out.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be using fsspec's GCS filesystem implementation instead.

https://github.com/fsspec/gcsfs/

```
>>> import gcsfs
>>> fs = gcsfs.GCSFileSystem(project='my-google-project')
>>> fs.ls('my-bucket')
['my-file.txt']
>>> with fs.open('my-bucket/my-file.txt', 'rb') as f:
...     print(f.read())
b'Hello, world'
```

https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#examples

Comment: thank you for the advise, this is new to me, and i tried it. instead i use fsspec.(because i need to have both "path" and "content" arguement.) are you familiar with fsspec form? if possible would you check for me on this? i get an error:TypeError: open() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given (reference code is on my original post) thank you